# If $\limsup_n a_n\leq c+\varepsilon$, then $a_n\leq c+\varepsilon$ for almost all n?

Tags: analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $a:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$, $c>0$ a constant and $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary.

Let $a\leq c+\varepsilon$.

Does then follow that 
$$
a_n\leq c+\varepsilon~\text{for almost all n}?
$$

---

(Almost all n  means all but finite many n.)

I am not sure how to prove that.

Comment: Is the assertion supposed to hold for all $\epsilon > 0$ or just for one particular $\epsilon$?

Comment: For one $\varepsilon>0$ that was chosen arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is wrong. Choose $c = \epsilon = 1$ and $a_n = 2 + \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: What about the following statement: $a\leq c$ for some constant c, then $a_n\leq c$ for almost all n?

Comment: This is exactly the same statement, only that you've exchanges $c + \epsilon$ with $c$.

Comment: As the example above is even converging... it is not even true for an ordinary limit.